# Application.LoadComponent cannot find resource

Tags: .net, wpf, resources

I have a xaml file in my project at `Ns1\Ns2\myfile.xaml`. It's build action is set to Page, with a custom tool of MSBuild:Compile. I'm trying to load this file in a static constructor:

```
namespace Ns1.Ns2 {
    internal class MyClass {
        static() {
            var obj = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/myfile.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run this code, it fails with an exception `cannot locate resource 'myfile.xaml'`. If I change the URI to an absolute URI:

```
var obj = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ns1/ns2/myfile.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));
```

it fails with `Cannot use absolute URI`. I get the same errors if I change the type of myfile.xaml to Resource.

How can I compile and reference myfile.xaml from code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should specify the assembly name:

```
Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/myfile.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
```

Alternatively, if the file has a code-behind class, you can just 'new' it, and the generated code will load the associated XAML.

Comment: In this case that would be `/WpfApplication1;ns1/ns2/myfile.xaml`? That does not work.

Comment: @thecoop I think You forgot to specify component.

Comment: Ah, that's not part of the path? Got it.

Comment: Works like a charm, any idea thought why the UriKind is Relative while it seems like an absolute path, since it specifies the assembly and path within the assebmy?

Comment: @EliArbel Thanks!

Comment: This helped me, my mistake was '/component' instead of 'component'